# How to install Debian if I have another Windows computer but don't want to format a USB stick?

Tags: windows, debian, grub

I have a Windows laptop and want to install Debian on another PC. I have a 128GB USB stick I wouldn't like to format. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a Debian ISO, I used netinst.
2. Using Double Commander (or any other tool but Double Commander is easy) extract the `.disk` , `dists`, `pool` directories from the ISO image to the USB stick. Double Commander just treats the ISO as a folder, you can Enter into it. I am not 100% `dists` is necessary but since it's 1M I couldn't be bothered to test it. I am not sure about `.disk` either but it looks like something d-i would test for when it tries to find the disk, doesn't it? As far as I understand https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=724931 you can't use the ISO as-is to install.
3. Either copy the entire `install.amd` directory or just the `initrd.gz` and `vmlinuz` files from there, nothing else is needed. I copied these two files to `I:\`, the root of my USB stick.
4. Grab Grub2 from https://www.aioboot.com/en/install-grub2-from-windows/ and perform the command outlined there, I did `grub-install.exe --boot-directory=I:\ --efi-directory=I: --removable --target=x86_64-efi`. It's possible grub2win off sourceforge works just as well. I haven't tested that.
5. Now `I:\` has a `grub` directory, change `grub.cfg` to:

   insmod fat
   insmod all_video
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid 4C66-B90C --set root
   linux /vmlinuz
   initrd /initrd.gz
   boot

The first insmod and search commands should be there, the rest is our own. If not, you can find the value of `--fs-uuid` by running the `vol` command from a command prompt on `I:`. That's it, now the Debian installer boots and will find the USB stick just fine.

[image]

Comment: Do you have remote access to the other PC, even with a simple crossover Ethernet cable? If so, you can use Unetbootin's command line arguments such as "installtype=HDD" and "targetdrive=X:\", where "X:" is the letter of a partition you'll create remotely on the second PC with Disk Management. From your main PC, you can run Unetbootin on the second PC to install Debian alongside Windows (?) on the newly created partition, then once in Debian, you can decide what to do with the existing Windows installation. The new boot entry will be added to the Windows bootloader, though.